# Suppose I have 100 integers and I sample 10 without repetition. What is the expected rank of the lowest out of 10 samples?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, ordinal-data, order-statistics

Suppose I have 100 integers and I sample 10 without replacement. What is the expected rank of the lowest out of 10 samples? i.e. my lowest integer in the 10-sample is kth smallest out of 100. what is k?

How would the answer change if I sampled with replacement?

Comment: Are the integers unique?

Comment: What do you guess and why? What have you tried. // The expected value of the smallest of ten observations from continuous dist'n $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1)$ is $1/11 = 0.090909,$ so I'd guess a bit below 10.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for pointing out. in fact the probably I am working on cannot guarantee that they are unique... but I guess assuming them unique should make the problem much simpler and it should also be a reasonable approximation to the non-unique problem, so for this question I am happy to assume they are unique.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To obtain an answer we must know how many ties there are among these $100$ integers and where they occur: that's too complicated and likely is not the intent of the question.  (Nevertheless, the techniques applied below continue to work.)  Henceforth, then, **suppose all these integers are unique.**  Without any loss of generality they might as well be the ordered set of their ranks, $1 \lt 2 \lt \cdots \lt 100.$

Let $S(k)$ be the chance that the smallest element of the sample is $k$ or larger. These events correspond to samples of $\{k, k+1, k+2, \ldots, 100\},$ a set with $101-k$ elements.

- When sampling without replacement, these constitute $\binom{101-k}{10}$ out of the $\binom{100}{10}$ equiprobable samples.
- When sampling with replacement, they constitute $(101-k)^{10}$ out of the $100^{10}$ equiprobable samples.

The expectation is the sum of the $S(k)$ beginning with $k=1.$  The two answers therefore are

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\binom{101-k}{10}}{\binom{100}{10}} = \frac{101}{11}$$

(without replacement) and

$$\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{k=1}^{100} \frac{(101-k)^{10}}{100^{10}} \\&=\frac{6(100)^{10} + 33(100)^9 + 55(100)^8 - 66(100)^6 + 66(100)^4 - 33(100)^2 + 5}{66(100)^9}
\end{aligned}$$

(with replacement).

As decimals they equal $9.\overline{18}$  and $9.599241\ldots,$ respectively.

Comment: Nice! Simulating with a million iterations, I got 9.18, 9.60, respectively.

Comment: @whuber: this is great, thank you! Can I know where the "66" came from in the final step of your derivation, for the "without replacement" situation?

Comment: @BruceET Thanks for your simulation, too!

Comment: The sum with replacement comes from expanding $(101-k)^{10}.$ Both sums can be evaluated using R as a calculator: `k = 1:100;  sum(choose(101-k,10)/ choose(100,10))` returns $9.181818$ and then
`sum((101-k)^10/100^10)` returns $9.599241.$

Comment: Simulations in R: `set.seed(1022);  s = replicate(10^6, min(sample(1:100, 10)));  mean(s)` returns $9.181042.$  // `s = replicate(10^6, min(sample(1:100, 10, rep=T)));  mean(s)` returns
$ 9.60545.$ // However, direct combinatorial computation as in @whuber's elegant answer is quicker and more accurate.

Comment: As you are making an implicit assumption of uniqueness of the 100 integers ( which the OP confirmed in a comment), I would add this to your answer (or to the question) because comments come and go or can be missed.

Comment: @Luca That's a good point: I will add it right away.

Comment: Re the "66" in the formula: this is equation (30) in the [Wolfram page about power sums](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html).  Formula (12) there is the general formula for integral powers other than $10.$